# Catching exceptions from other methods

Tags: c#, exception

I have a class which contains several methods.

One of the methods runs in a while loop (MainMethod).

I call out to helper methods in the same class from MainMethod.

The Try Catch is contained within MainMethod where most of the execution occurs.

If an exception occurs in a helper method which doesn't contain a Try Catch, will it be caught further up? i.e. inside MainMethod which called the helper method.

```
     class Class1
     {
        public MainMethod() 
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    // ...
                    // ...
                    // ...
                    HelperMethod();
                    // ...
                    // ...
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    // logger.log(e.ToString();
                    // throw e;
                    // ...
                }

            }
        }

        public HelperMethod() 
        {
            // No Try Catch
            // if (today == "tuesday") program explodes.
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you throw an exception from `HelperMethod` and see yourself?

Comment: The reason I asked on here was because I know it would be answered fairly quickly. It also acts as a resource for anyone who is wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If a method has no try/catch block it will "bubble up" the stack and be caught by the next handler up the chain.  If there is no handler, that's when your program terminates because an exception was "unhandled".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will. Something like this:

```
public class Helper
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

        throw new InvalidCastException("I don't like this cast.");
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Your argument is invalid.");
    }
}

public class Caller
{
    public void CallHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            new Helper().SomeMethod();

        }
        catch (ArgumentException exception)
        {
            // Do something there
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Do something here
        }

        try
        {
            new Helper().SomeOtherMethod();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exception)
        {
            // Do something there
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if caller application handles that specific type of exception, specific catch block will be called.

IMHO, it is good to handle specific exceptions that may be thrown by methods you call from your code. However, that also means that author of method you are calling created a decent document sharing exceptions that we need to expect from his code.